# Mouse pad stops working, restart in driver solves issue temporarily, but is much to frequent

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, device-manager, input-device

For the last half of year, I have been pestered with a touchpad problem and have not tried to try solving the issue until recently.

My touchpad is a precision touchpad as described by Windows. There are **three states** the mouse can be in at any time: 1, Working completely (including gestures); 2, Mouse movement works but gestures do not work; 3, Not working at all (no mouse movement not gestures). These states aren't defined by the computer, just for referencing the issues for resolution.

State 3 happens several times a day usually, and sometimes State 3 sometimes recurs soon after myself restarting the drivers which fixes them temporarily. The majority of the time however, it is in state 2, which isn't as annoying.

I want to solve the issue by preventing both occurrences (state 3 at least) forever.

When State 3 occurs, the mouse disappears from the screen and becomes no longer interactive. This issue is temporarily fixed by restarting a specific driver: I2C HID Device. I do this by disabling and enabling the driver by Device Manager. (I also made myself a batch script that does it for me using Devcon.)

When I "restart" the driver/device, It returns to state 1; however, it usually goes back into 2 and 3 from a couple seconds to couples hours.

Specs:

I have a Dell Inspiron 13-7353 with Windows 10 Home. I am using Fast Insider Builds (however this means nothing, as this issue persisted even on official releases)

From msinfo32→Components→Input→Pointing Device:

```
Item    Value   
Hardware Type   PS/2 Compatible Mouse   
Number of Buttons   0   
Status  OK  
PNP Device ID   ACPI\DLL06FD\4&188324C1&0   
Power Management Supported  No  
Double Click Threshold  Not Available   
Handedness  Not Available   
IRQ Channel IRQ 12  
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\i8042prt.sys (10.0.16237.1001, 104.00 KB (106,496 bytes), 7/1/2017 23:47)   

Hardware Type   HID-compliant mouse 
Number of Buttons   0   
Status  OK  
PNP Device ID   HID\DLL06FE&COL01\5&1882E9A2&1&0000 
Power Management Supported  No  
Double Click Threshold  Not Available   
Handedness  Not Available   
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\mouhid.sys (10.0.16237.1001, 32.00 KB (32,768 bytes), 7/1/2017 23:47)
```

For those with the most experience I output-ed a lot of related driver information below.

Most & More, Touchpad Related Drivers Information (more than already shown) I put in **[this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/g92DQgEG)** by using the Windows Utility Devcon.

Hypothesis: I am certainly no expert, but I am guessing that somewhere in the driver settings or something a or multiple flags are constantly being switched off (or negatively on) causing states 2 & 3. As such when I "restart" the I2C driver, the flag resets allowing mouse movement and gestures, returning it back into state 1.

Another Observation: When I use the touch-screen prolonged use, it often causes state 3. (Likely because it removes the mouse from the screen, then maybe somehow removes "the mouse" itself, then causing the issue 3)

EDIT: When an external mouse is connected, the pointer will always move and reactivates the mousepad to go to phase 2 (sometimes 1).

When I say "mouse," I mean the pointer.

All the help is most appreciated. Comment below for more questions or things you want to know.